# discord.py guild.members не дает всех участников

Tags: discord.py

Мне нужно было получить количество людей на сервере:

```
g = bot.get_guild(502396222963843072)
print(len(g.members))
```

Однако мне написалось 60 когда на сервере 2000 человек.

Answer (score 0):

```
members = await g.fetch_members(limit=3000, after=None).flatten()
```

members теперь список людей на сервере